# How to force a line break in List of Figure caption in case of detecting a bracket

Tags: pdftex, captions, tocloft

I would like to automatically add a linebreak to the captions in List of Figures in case it detects starting of a bracket [ex: '(']. Currently, it looks like below

[image]

However, I am looking for something like this:

[image]

I am using book documentclass with the followings for caption:

```
\usepackage[font=small,labelsep=period,format=hang,skip=5pt,justification=centering]{caption} %caption 
 alignment
\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
```

Comment: You say you want a linebreak when there is a ( in the caption text. But your example only shows a linebreak before the second ( and not before the first (. Please explain more clearly what you want.

Comment: You can specify a separate title for the LOF: `\caption[Center of glazing (Double - no blind) temperature provile \protect\newline (Bolzano Winter)]
{Center of glazing (Double - no blind) temperature provile (Bolzano Winter)}` Creating a parser smart enough to automatically do this would be much more difficutl

Comment: Thanks, @JohnKormylo, the solution solves my problem.